# Delete checked items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

In my app I have ListView with checkboxes. I have delete button too. When I press delete button I want to delete all items from ListView which are checked. Is there any method which checks all items in ListView and deletes all items from ListView.? If there is not then how can i get my result..?

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0):

Yes its easy.

You have list items, so you know how many check boxes are there in listview. position is associated with each listview row. So set position as tag for the checkboxes in listview's getview method. i.e. checkbox.setTag(position).

Now fire the checkbox change event and store all checkbox state into boolean array. when user press delete button, just delete items whose value is true in boolean array.